# Assign variable names to different files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to open various text files simulataneously in python. I want to assign a unique name to each file. I have tried the follwoing but it is not working:

```
for a in [1,2,11]:
    "DOS%s"%a=open("DOS%s"%a,"r")
```

Instead I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You're misusing the word *simultaneously*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you always have to have the namespace declared before assignment, either on a previous line or on the left of a statement. Anyway you can do:

```
files = {f:open("DOS%s" % f) for f in [1,2,11]}
```

then access files like:

```
files[1].read()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dict :

```
files = {}
for a in [1,2,11]:
    files["DOS%s"%a] = open("DOS%s"%a,"r")
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because you're trying to assign a value to something that is not a variable. This is pretty basic stuff, so I'd suggest that you do some sort of introductory programming course.

When you need a string as a lookup key, a *dictionary* is your friend:

```
files = {}
for a in [1, 2, 11]:
    filename = 'DOS%s' % a
    files[filename] = open(filename, 'r')
```

Comment: a shorter way `dosfiles = {"DOS%s"%a: open("DOS%s"%a,"r") for a in [1,2,11]}`

Comment: @comiventor A lot less readable in my opinion. Newlines are not your enemy :)

Comment: surely not @Henrik :) I wanted to break the dictionary comprehension into two lines but pressing enter in comment just posts it instead of newline.

Comment: Come to think of it, it's not a bad idea to do this in a comprehension, but the double formatting string bugs me.